# PHP only allow file to be downloaded via page

Tags: php

I've got some mp3 files that i'd like to allow only paying members to listen and download via a page. the problem is, if I do

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from website.com
```

it successfully stops users from downloading at www.example.com/song/song.mp3

I can do this

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
```

but it only allows users to download. if I have a html5 player to allow the user to stream before downloading, it says **"the audio could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported."** If I cancel the lines from htaccess, it will be able to stream.

here's the player

```
<video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto"
            data-setup="{}">
<source src="song/song.mp3" type='audio/mp3' />
</video>
```

Is there any way I can allow paying users to download and stream from that specific page only, and restricting everyone else? Thanks

Comment: Is the HTML 5 player on the same domain (matched exactly)? If not, you'll want to set a crossorigin request to force the auth header to be sent. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: Hi, the playe is on the same domain. I added it to the question so you can have a look

Comment: Use the proper mime-type?

Comment: you mean <?php header('Content-type: text/html');?>  ?

Comment: The mime type has nothing to do with your problem. As far as I can see you are still accessing the original mp3 file, so the header in your download script doesn't affect it.

Comment: Next question: has the user already authenticated on the page in the current browser? Without testing, the video request probably won't throw up the username/password option: you need to have the user visit the /song directory first, enter username/password and then download the song. What would be an easier option is to use a cookie/session system: allow a user to log in, create the session and then download the file only if the session is valid. This would be more transparent.

Comment: I've got a few conditions set, so the user will not be able to access the page if the conditions are not met. In this case, I wont need the htaccess or the headers at all. but then, my problem would be how can I stop someone from downloading directly via link?

Comment: the other alternative would be adding the htaccess and headers. then my problem would be getting the song to stream. that's giving me the error I stated above. also, I read that it would require a large amount of ram as the files are downloaded before it is served to the user. so if there's another option, please share. thanks

Comment: itd, it's the htaccess that's stopping my song from streaming if i'm not mistaken